# doubt in drawing graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have generated the tikz codes from geogebra...

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw[->,color=black] (-2,0) -- (5,0);
\foreach \x in {-2,-1,1,2,3,4}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
\draw[->,color=black] (0,-1) -- (0,5);
\foreach \y in {-1,1,2,3,4}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt);
\draw[color=black] (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize $0$};
\clip(-2,-1) rectangle (5,5);
%\draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=5.00000000131904E-6:5.0] plot(\x,{((\x)*>*0)*(1+1/(\x))});
\draw (1.04,2.87) node[anchor=north west] {$(1,1+a)$};
\draw (0,2)-- (1,2);
\draw (1,2)-- (1,0);
\draw (-1.5,2.66) node[anchor=north west] {$1+a$};
\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=qqqqff] (1,2) circle (1.5pt);
\fill [color=qqqqff] (0,2) circle (1.5pt);
\fill [color=qqqqff] (1,0) circle (1.5pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And I am getting the diagram like the following...

[image]

But I should have my diagram as..[image] the curve is missing here.. what should i do to get the graph.. help me..

Comment: you mean even if you uncomment the plot line and remove the `>` and not multiply by zero?

Answer (score 2):

See the correct syntax of `plot` in pgf manual arround p 329. Maybe Geogebra makes some mistakes...

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0,0,1}


\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45]

\draw[->,color=black] (-2,0) -- (5,0);
\foreach \x in {-2,-1,1,2,3,4}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
\draw[->,color=black] (0,-1) -- (0,5);
\foreach \y in {-1,1,2,3,4}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt);
\draw[color=black] (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize $0$};
\clip(-2,-1) rectangle (5,5);
\draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=.1:5.0] plot(\x,{1+1/(\x)});
\draw (1.04,2.87) node[anchor=north west] {$(1,1+a)$};
\draw (0,2)-- (1,2);
\draw (1,2)-- (1,0);
\draw (-1.5,2.66) node[anchor=north west] {$1+a$};
\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=qqqqff] (1,2) circle (1.5pt);
\fill [color=qqqqff] (0,2) circle (1.5pt);
\fill [color=qqqqff] (1,0) circle (1.5pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\caption{Nice curve !}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can we give figure number and caption inside the tikzpicture environment.@Tarass

Comment: No, if one tries the answer is `not in outer mode`. See my update, tikzpicture must be inside the figure.